# Globally set background color of buttons, except accessory buttons in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiappearance

I am using the below code to make all my buttons in an application the same color.  However the accessory icon in the UITTableView row also has it.  Is there a way to ignore it in the table view?

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UIView` conforms to the `UIAppearanceContainer` protocol.

So you should use `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` to distinct buttons depending on where they are contained in.

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];    
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableView class], nil] setBackgroundColor:nil];
```

It would be best to use the `UITableViewCell` subclass instead of the table view.

Comment: That worked but it was `[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewCell class], nil] setBackgroundColor:nil];`

Comment: @MikeFlynn Ah right, corrected the answer. Sorry, was typing on my Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UITableView class]] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor differentColor]];
```